# Sorting months with pre-defined order?

Tags: design, sorting

I want to sort the months of the year starting at any month, but January needs to show up after December if January isn't the starting point. Can I do that in an array or do I need a special data structure or algorithm to do that?

Comment: how sorting order is controlled, design or run-time?

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do this with just an array. `[Dec,Jan,Feb,...Oct,Nov]` then you can iterate through with `month mod 12` and it will produce a sorted list that can wrap around from Dec to Jan. You can simply stop iterating at January if you only want that month to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Java-ish code:

```
public void sortMonths(int START) {
    // Jan = 0, ... , Dez = 11
    int[] myArray = new int[12];
    for (int i = START; i < 12; ++i) {
        myArray[i - START] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < START; ++i) {
        myArray[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: care to elaborate for down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Many sorters let you provide your own comparator which dictates the sort order.  Write one that implements your rules and and supply it to the sort function.